# LXML xpath does not detect in a "dirty" html file, however after indenting and cleaning it, it succeeds

Tags: html, python-3.x, python-requests, header, lxml

Every sort of help will be extremely appreciated. I am building a parser to a web-site. I am trying to detect an element using lxml package, the element has a pretty simple relative xpath: `'//div[@id="productDescription"]'`. When I am manually going to the web page, making 'view page source' and copying the html string to local html file, everything works perfectly. However, if I download the file automatically:

```
headers = {"user-Agent": "MY SCRAPER USER-AGENT", "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate", "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "DNT": "1","Connection": "close", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1"}
product_HTML_bytes = requests.get(product_link, headers=headers, proxies={'http': "***:***"}).content
product_HTML_str = product_HTML_bytes.decode()
main_data = html.fromstring(product_HTML_str)
product_description_tags = main_data.xpath('//div[@id="productDescription"]')
...
```

I get nothing (and the data does exist in the file). I had also tried to first scrape a sample of pages using the same request.get with the same headers and so on, saving the files locally and then cleaning the extra spaces and indenting the document manually using this html formatter: https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html and then boom, it works again. However, I couldn't put my finger on what exactly changes in the files, but I was pretty sure extra spaces and indented tabs should not make a difference.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in Advance

Edit:

URL: [https://www.amazon.com/Samsung-MicroSDXC-Adapter-MB-ME128GA-AM/dp/B06XWZWYVP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XWZWYVP)
cause pasting it here is impossible because the file exceeds the length limit, I uploaded them to the web.

The not working HTML: https://easyupload.io/231pdd

The indented, clean, and formatted HTML page: https://easyupload.io/a9oiyh

Comment: Check if the page is dynamically loaded with jscript; if so, requests won't work and you'll need to use something like selenium.

Comment: So why does it works again after I format the downloaded file using requests.get? And how do you check such a thing?

Comment: Go to that url, disable javascript in your browser and reload the page. If the target data is missing, you know it's loaded dynamically.

Comment: @JackFleeting still appears, this is not the issue

Comment: Then, if you can, edit the post and paste a representative sample of the html. Or the url, if possible.

Comment: @JackFleeting - done

Comment: Well, it's a long story, but it seems that, while you can't do it with lxml, you can do it with BeautifulSoup (using the lxml parser!). If you're interested, I can post the problem with lxml and the BeautifulSoup solution.

Comment: @JackFleeting, I am more than interested. I would also like to hear the whole story.

Answer (score 1):

For some strange reason, it seems the the lxml library mangles the text output of `requests.get()` when the output is filtered through the `lxml.html.fromstring()` method. I have no idea why.

The target data is still there, no doubt:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(product_HTML_str,'lxml') #note that the lxml parser is used here!
for elem in soup.select_one('#productDescription p'):
    print(elem.strip())
```

Output:

> Simply the right card. With stunning speed and reliability, the...
>   etc.

I personally much prefer using xpath in lxml to `find()` and css selectors methods used by BeautifulSoup, but this time BeautifulSoup wins...